# How to use tabulate module with user input and loops in Python?

Tags: python, tabulate

I have made a program in which the user enters marks of the students and Python tells the average marks and tells us that if the score is satisfactory, good or excellent. It is given below:

```
from array import array as arr
import numpy as np
from tabulate import *

marks = []
stu_mks = input("Enter the marks of the students(entering STOP would end the process): ")
marks.append(stu_mks)

while stu_mks.lower() != 'stop':
     stu_mks = input("Enter the marks of the students(entering STOP would end the process): ")
     marks.append(stu_mks)

del marks[-1]

array_marks = np.array(marks)
float_marks = array_marks.astype(np.float)

avg = 0
for i in float_marks:
    avg += i

print("The average marks are", avg / len(float_marks))

for x in float_marks:
    if x % 1 == 0:
        print(int(x), end = "\t")
        if x < 40:
            print("NOT SATISFACTORY")
        if x > 40 and x <= 74:
            print("SATISFACTORY")
        if x >= 75 and x <= 89:
            print("GOOD")
        if x >= 90:
            print("EXCELLENT")
    else:
        print(x, end = "\t")
        if x < 40:
            print("NOT SATISFACTORY")
        if x > 40 and x <= 74:
            print("SATISFACTORY")
        if x >= 75 and x <= 89:
            print("GOOD")
        if x >= 90:
            print("EXCELLENT")
```

What I actually want is that the marks and their review(i.e. good, excellent, etc.) are displayed in tabular format. That is why I imported `tabulate` module, but the problem is that I don't know how to add each row as a list or a dictionary in any variable and then tabulate it. I tried very hard, but all in vain. So, please suggest me a way to do the same and also it would be very appreciable if there is a better way to run this program in less lines of code. Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have solved it! It's quite easy. The code is the following :

```
from array import array as arr
import numpy as np
from tabulate import *

marks = []
stu_mks = input("Enter the marks of the students(entering STOP would end the process): ")
marks.append(stu_mks)

while stu_mks.lower() != 'stop':
     stu_mks = input("Enter the marks of the students(entering STOP would end the process): ")
     marks.append(stu_mks)

del marks[-1]

array_marks = np.array(marks)
float_marks = array_marks.astype(np.float)

avg = 0
for i in float_marks:
    avg += i

print("The average marks are", avg / len(float_marks))

marks_list = []
remarks_list = []

for x in float_marks:
    if x % 1 == 0:
        marks_list.append(int(x))
        if x < 40:
            remarks_list.append("NOT SATISFACTORY")
        if x > 40 and x <= 74:
            remarks_list.append("SATISFACTORY")
        if x >= 75 and x <= 89:
            remarks_list.append("GOOD")
        if x >= 90:
            remarks_list.append("EXCELLENT")
    else:
        marks_list.append(x)
        if x < 40:
            remarks_list.append("NOT SATISFACTORY")
        if x > 40 and x <= 74:
            remarks_list.append("SATISFACTORY")
        if x >= 75 and x <= 89:
            remarks_list.append("GOOD")
        if x >= 90:
            remarks_list.append("EXCELLENT")

table = {'Marks Scored' : marks_list, 'Remarks' : remarks_list}

print(tabulate(table, headers='keys', tablefmt='fancy_grid', stralign = 'center', numalign = 'center'))
```

I made a dictionary named `table` and made two empty lists named `marks_list` and `remarks_list`. In the `marks_list` I appended all the marks in the order that the user enters and in the same way, all the remarks corresponding to the marks were appended to the `remarks_list`.
Only the following code block was edited by me:

```
marks_list = []
remarks_list = []

for x in float_marks:
    if x % 1 == 0:
        marks_list.append(int(x))
        if x < 40:
            remarks_list.append("NOT SATISFACTORY")
        if x > 40 and x <= 74:
            remarks_list.append("SATISFACTORY")
        if x >= 75 and x <= 89:
            remarks_list.append("GOOD")
        if x >= 90:
            remarks_list.append("EXCELLENT")
    else:
        marks_list.append(x)
        if x < 40:
            remarks_list.append("NOT SATISFACTORY")
        if x > 40 and x <= 74:
            remarks_list.append("SATISFACTORY")
        if x >= 75 and x <= 89:
            remarks_list.append("GOOD")
        if x >= 90:
            remarks_list.append("EXCELLENT")

table = {'Marks Scored' : marks_list, 'Remarks' : remarks_list}

print(tabulate(table, headers='keys', tablefmt='fancy_grid', stralign = 'center', numalign = 'center'))
```

Then I followed the general method of making a table which you can find here:

**Link 1:** https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-easily-create-tables-in-python-2eaea447d8fd

**Link 2:** https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/

***BINGO!!!***

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Community♦ I have edited my answer. So, kindly check now it is fine.